# Using L'Hôpital's rule to obtain the particular integral for special resonance case of ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

As I mentioned before in [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217017/692431), I kept investigating the method that looks similar to [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) of obtaining the particular integral for special case of ordinary differential equation. I found that this method worked for every case I tried although the condition for applying L'Hôpital's rule, both numerator and denominator approach zero, is not fulfilled. These are some examples

$\ddot u+\alpha^2u=A\cos{\omega t}+B\sin{\omega t}$
The particular integral is
$A\frac{\cos{\omega t}}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}+B\frac{\sin{\omega t}}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}$
but for the equation
$\ddot u+\alpha^2u=A\cos{\alpha t}+B\sin{\alpha t}$
then the denominator will be zero, so both numerator and denominator are differentiated with respect to $\omega$, then it is substituted with $\alpha$ which produces
$A\frac{t\sin{\alpha t}}{2\alpha}-B\frac{t\cos{\alpha t}}{2\alpha}$
which is the solution that can be obtained using other calculus methods.

$\ddot u+\alpha^2u=At\cos{\omega t}+Bt\sin{\omega t}$
The particular integral is
$A\left(\frac{t\cos{\omega t}}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}+\frac{2\omega \sin{\omega t}}{(\alpha^2-\omega^2)^2}\right)+B\left(\frac{t\sin{\omega t}}{\alpha^2-\omega^2}-\frac{2\omega \cos{\omega t}}{(\alpha^2-\omega^2)^2}\right)$
for the equation
$\ddot u+\alpha^2u=At\cos{\alpha t}+Bt\sin{\alpha t}$
Using the same method, the particular integral is
$A\left(\frac{t^2\sin{\alpha t}}{4\alpha}+\frac{t\cos{\alpha t}}{4\alpha^2}\right)+B\left(-\frac{t^2\cos{\alpha t}}{4\alpha}+\frac{t\sin{\alpha t}}{4\alpha^2}\right)$

$\ddddot u+\alpha^4u=e^{\omega t}$
The particular integral is
$\frac{e^{\omega t}}{\alpha^4+\omega^4}$
for the equation
$\ddddot u+\alpha^4u=e^{(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2})\alpha t}$
The particular integral is
$-\frac{1+i}{4\sqrt 2\alpha^3}te^{(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2})\alpha t}$

My question is, is this method valid for all cases? And if the answer is yes, can anyone provide a reference or a proof to it?